# Laravel Query Builder - whereHas with query select value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am very confused how the whereHas function is working ?

I want to check a column inside of whereHas from Main Query.

**ClientSeatController.php**

```php
$seats = ClientSeat::where('clientId',$req->clientId)
          ->wherehas('services',function($query) use($req){
            $query->where('clientId',$req->clientId);
          })->get();
```

ClientSeat.php (Relation)

```php
public function services(){
    return $this->hasOne(ClientSeatService::class,'clientSeatId','clientSeatId');
}
```

toSql();

```php
select * from `sln_client_seats` where `clientId` = 3 and exists (select * from `sln_client_seat_services` where `sln_client_seats`.`clientSeatId` = `sln_client_seat_services`.`clientSeatId` and `clientId` = 3)
```

I need the query like below.

```php
select * from `sln_client_seats` where `clientId` = 3 and exists (select * from `sln_client_seat_services` where `sln_client_seat_services`.`clientSeatId` =`sln_client_seats`.`clientSeatId`  and `clientId` = 3)
```

I want to check the **clientSeatId** of **client_seat_services** table with the clientSeatId of client_seats table column  inside whereHas function.

The query is not executing correctly the expected.

Please help me.

Comment: Is it throwing any error ?

Comment: Not getting any error, Getting empty result. I suppose to get 3 rows from table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$query->where('clientSeatId','client_seats.clientSeatId');` from your `whereHas` closure.  Your `ClientSeat::services()` method is already defining that part of the relationship.  The way you have it written there would literally place the string "client_seats.clientSeatId" in the query, rather than the actual Id value.  So you won't get an error, and all your results will be empty.

Comment: When I remove the code based on your comment I am getting the query like in updated question. Its wrong Actually. The where clause of exists query is checking as wrongly. `sln_client_seats`.`clientSeatId` = `sln_client_seat_services`.`clientSeatId`

Comment: The query now matches the query from "I need the query like below". Only the sides are switched, but that's irrelevant.